# Laravel 6 - Accessor appends not called in relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, accessor

I use Laravel 6 and I want access to avatar attribute from user when I use posts() relation.

User model:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'avatar',
];

/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function posts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAvatarAttribute(): string
{
    return sprintf('https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?s=500', md5($this->email));
}
```

The code of my controller:

```
$topic = Topic::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

foreach ($topic->posts()->get() as $post) {
    dd($post->user->avatar); // return null
}
```

Post model:

```
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I get the name of user with `$post->user->name` but avatar attribute is not called.

Comment: can you post your your `post` model too? specially its `user` relationship

Comment: Thanks @HafezDivandari for suggestion! Done!

Comment: it shouldn't happen but try `$topic->posts()->with('user')->get()` and check if it works!

Comment: No it does not works...

Comment: wow it's weird! maybe full code of these models give us a clue! I don't know!

Comment: You can get the accessor if you call it directly from the user? `User::find($id)->avatar;`

Comment: Does your `User` model have an actual attribute named `avatar` defined? If so, that would prevent the accessor from working.

Comment: @patricus No model with avatar attribute in project.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes, it works but I don't want use it.